# Simple MySQL loop syntax error

Tags: mysql, loops

Here is my simple loop

```
SET @id = 16;
SET @res = @id;

simple_loop: LOOP
SELECT @p := c_parent FROM categories WHERE c_id = @id;
IF @p > 0 THEN
    SET @id = @p;
    SET @res = @res + ',' + @p;
ELSE
    LEAVE simple_loop;
END IF;
END LOOP simple_loop;

SELECT @res;
```

Executing code in phpMyAdmin gets standard error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '**simple_loop: LOOP
>      SELECT @p := c_parent FROM categories WHERE c_id = @id**' at line 1

My knowledge of MySQL is shallow. Please show me the correct syntax for this simple operation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mysql's documentation on [loop](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html) indicates: loops can only be used withing a [compund statement block](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html) within a stored procedure.

So, the solution is to create a stored procedure out of the above code using [create procedure command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) and include your code within it in a begin ... end blcok, observing its syntax requirements.